# How to configure Delegating Session Factory in spring sftp inbound channel adaptor

Tags: spring, spring-integration

We want to delegate the session-factory at run time to spring sftp inbound channel adapter. For that we have done the below configuration.

We have gone through the spring-sftp integration docs but we are not sure how to set the session-factory attribute value via java. Could you please suggest us how to delegate the session-factory run time in spring sftp inbound channel adapter using Delegating Session Factory.

XML Configuration

```
<beans>
<bean id="defaultSftpSessionFactoryOne" class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="**.***.**.***" />
    <property name="port" value="**" />
    <property name="user" value="######" />
    <property name="password" value="######" />
    <property name="allowUnknownKeys" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="defaultSftpSessionFactoryTwo"     class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="**.***.**.***" />
    <property name="port" value="**" />
    <property name="user" value="######" />
    <property name="password" value="######" />
    <property name="allowUnknownKeys" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="delegatingSessionFactory"     class="org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.DelegatingSessionFactory">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean id="factoryLocator"
            class="org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.DefaultSessionFactoryLocator">
            <constructor-arg name="factories">
                <map>
                    <entry key="one" value-ref="defaultSftpSessionFactoryOne"></entry>
                    <entry key="two" value-ref="defaultSftpSessionFactoryTwo"></entry>
                </map>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<int:channel id="receiveChannel" />

<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpInbondAdapter" auto-startup="false"
    channel="receiveChannel" session-factory="delegatingSessionFactory"
    local-directory="C:\\Users\\sftp" remote-directory="/tmp/archive"
    auto-create-local-directory="true" delete-remote-files="false"
    filename-regex=".*\.txt$">
    <int:poller cron="0/10 * * * * ?">
    </int:poller>
</int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

java code

```
ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
DelegatingSessionFactory<String> dsf = (DelegatingSessionFactory<String>) ac.getBean("delegatingSessionFactory");
SessionFactory<String> one = dsf.getFactoryLocator().getSessionFactory("one");
SessionFactory<String> two = dsf.getFactoryLocator().getSessionFactory("two");
dsf.setThreadKey("two");
SourcePollingChannelAdapter spca = (SourcePollingChannelAdapter) ac.getBean("sftpInbondAdapter");
spca.start();
```

Comment: Add java tag to question

Answer (score 1):

The delegating session factory was really intended for outbound adapters and gateways. Typically, inbound adapters don't switch to different servers.

Setting the thread key on the `main` thread like that does nothing.

You need to set/clear the key on the thread that invokes the adapter; this is shown for outbound adapters [in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-dsf).

For inbound adapters you need to do it on the poller thread.

I don't know what criteria you will use to select the factory, but you can use a [smart poller](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#__smart_polling) to do it.